# how do I DEFINE this?

Tags: php

I need a definition for a macro-like string in php which would literally be interpreted as this string, but I need is to refer to the line and file where the string is placed rather than my defs.php file...

```
define ("REDIRECT_FROM"," (".`____FILE____`." line:".`____LINE____`.")");

redirectTo("login.php",REDIRECT_FROM);
```

would result as:

```
redirected from abc.php line: 59
```

Hope I was clear. (the redirected from is implemented in the `redirectTo()` function of course)

Thanks!

Comment: Why does it have to be a constant? Can you not just make it a function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with `define()` - it sets constants, not macros.

A possible solution is using a function and a backtrace:

```
function called_from(){
  $trace = debug_backtrace();
  $item = $trace[0];
  return " ({$item['file']} line:{$item['line']})";
}
```

You would then call:

```
redirectTo("login.php", called_from());
```

You could also just build this logic into your `redirectTo()` function.

An example: http://codepad.org/CGUXWgAB

Answer (score 0):

I dont think thats possible, and its also not a good way of doing this anyway. You could do the parsing in redirectTo() and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php to backtrack the callstack.